# Jenkins Artifactory Integration

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I am using the `Jenkins Artifactory plugin` to publish build artifacts.

I renamed my job on Jenkins but I still see the old name of the job under Artifactory "Builds".

I am new to Artifactory (used Nexus in the past) and I am not sure if there's anything I need to do on Artifactory side to make the necessary name change.

Thanks,
Bella

Answer (score 1):

Artifactory does not discard old builds unless you specifically instruct to do so by deleting those builds so what you're seeing is just the builds from the 'old' job.

Now that you have renamed the job new builds (with the new name) will start showing in the Builds pane once you've started the job.

If you'd like to discard the old builds (from the old jenkins job) you can simply do it from the Builds pane or with the [REST api](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeleteBuilds)

Comment: Thanks for your response fundeldman.  I did not see the new build under the Builds pane after renaming the job and running it.  The only way I got it to work is to create a new job by copying the old build to a new job and giving it a new name.  I don't know if this is a bug that has to do with my job configuration (it's a multi config job).  I am just glad it's working now.